# Result for finite Borel measures, can it be extended to measures which are finite on every compact subset of $\Bbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I came across the following result:
Let $\mu$ be a finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$.
Then $\inf_{0<r\leq 1} \frac{\mu(x,r)}{r}>0$ for $\mu$ almost every x.
Can we extend this to any Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ which is finite on all compact Borel sets? Thanks!

Comment: Assuming that $(x,r)$ is an interval I would expect some restrictions on $x$. What e.g. if $x>1$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course. Given $a$, define $\nu$ by $$d\nu=\chi_{(a,a+1)}d\mu.$$Then $\nu$ is a finite measure, so the result holds for $\nu$, and hence for $\mu$, for $\nu$-almost every $x$. *Hence* for $\mu$-almost every $x\in(a,a+1)$.

Comment: Thanks, so basically we can say $inf_{0<r\leq 1}\frac{\mu(x,r)}{r} >0$ for $\mu$ almost every x by taking countable unions over (n,n+1)?